# How to configure Telerik in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have been working with ASP.NET for a while, but I have never worked with such old applications (which were made more than 10 years ago). At this moment I have a problem with the **Telerik** license, because I'm trying to locate and configure the licenseKey but I can't find the location where the files needed to modify them are located.

I was checking the Web.config but the license key is not there, I was also looking for the LicenseFile.xml file as indicated in the documentation but I can't find this file in the project nor in the location of the C: disk.

Finally I did a global search in the project code and I can't find where the license can be configured.

Do any of you know where I can locate the license to be able to configure it? Please I need to make some adjustments on it. Thank you very much for your help